# Unity Android :Unity doesn't load Android.Runtime.JNIEnv:AndroidValueManager

Tags: android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, xamarin, virtual-reality

I have a little problem. Unity doesn't load Android.Runtime.JNIEnv:AndroidValueManager. I don't know where this error comes from and how to repair it...

My error logs :

```
2021/06/22 10:09:33.456 5302 5323 Warn   TypeRef ResolutionScope not yet handled (134) for .JniValueManager in image /data/app/com.perform_vr.fitimmersion-AxYvjkyiPv3DPaA-wNwHhw==/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/Mono.Android.dll
2021/06/22 10:09:33.467 5302 5323 Error Unity TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv:AndroidValueManager' (16) due to: Could not resolve type with token 0100008f (from typeref, class/assembly JniValueManager, ) assembly: type:JniValueManager member:(null) signature:<none>
2021/06/22 10:09:33.467 5302 5323 Error Unity   at FitImmersion.Classes.MainController.ProcessDownload (FitImmersion.Classes.VideoInfo tr, System.Boolean update, System.Int32[] nums) [0x000fa] in <21b3d70927644252b1b0ae8a443a3803>:0
2021/06/22 10:09:33.467 5302 5323 Error Unity   at FitImmersion.Activities.VideoSelectActivity+<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<UpdateList>b__0 () [0x00011] in <21b3d70927644252b1b0ae8a443a3803>:0
2021/06/22 10:09:33.467 5302 5323 Error Unity   at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () [0x00010] in <fb0ce9ab519b43309a57d555bb8920f7>:0
2021/06/22 10:09:33.467 5302 5323 Error Unity   at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00022] in <fb0ce9ab519b43309a57d555bb8920f7>:0
2021/06/22 10:09:33.467 5302 5323 Error Unity   at UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () [0x0001c] in <adfa9916be9e467097f9456e7e67ce81>:0
2021/06/22 10:09:33.467 5302 5323 Error Unity   at UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) [0x00009] in <adfa9916be9e467097f9456e7e67ce81>:0
2021/06/22 10:09:33.467 5302 5323 Error Unity   at
```

After trying to reimport Mono.Android.dll, I've got these errors :

```
  Unloading broken assembly Assets/Plugins/Mono.Android.dll, this assembly can cause crashes in the runtime.
```

Where can I find an unbroken assembly Mono.android.dll?

Thanks a lot for your answers,
Lilian